# Show latest item added to an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I can't believe that I couldn't find a solution to this after searching google and SO for a half-hour.

I've got an `ObservableCollection<string>` in my ViewModel that a `ListBox` in my View is bound to:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Output}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

When a button is clicked, a new thread does some stuff and, using an Observable, the VM monitors strings coming back from that async operation and adds the strings to its `Output` `ObservableCollection`. The strings are getting added with no problem, but how to I get the view to always show the latest item (the one most recently added)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your item show up in the list but just farther down? If that is the case all you need to do is tell the list to scroll that item into view. You can do this by subscribing to the ColllectionChanged of the ListBox.Items property. To do this is a little tricky because you have to cast it but you can do so with code like this:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)MainListBox.Items).CollectionChanged +=  ListBox_CollectionChanged;
```

Then inside that event you can add code like this:

```
private void ListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                 MainListBox.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[0]);
            }, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
        }
    }
```

Also I just found a way you can do this with an attached property that is pretty cool. Check it out here:
http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/listbox-automatically-scroll-currentitem-into-view/

Comment: No dice - the `newListItem` is always null. And the code you first posted didn't work, probably because it was being triggered before the item existed in the ListBox collection. Thanks though.

Comment: If you set the `newListItem` directly to `e.NewItems[0]`, it actually works. However, if there are duplicate items in adjacent slots (e.g. the same text repeated x times), only the first will be scrolled to. Change your code and I'll select your answer.

Comment: Done - notice the link to the attached property method as well.

Comment: The attached property is a neat idea, but it's focused on the ListBox's CurrentItem - in the past, I've had problems using that property to scroll to (it doesn't always seem that the CurrentItem is set to the latest item in the ListBox's Collection). Your code works just fine.

Comment: What's with all the (probably often redundant) Dispatcher-use? (Also does not look like an operation for `SystemIdle` to me)

Comment: @H.B. I wondered the same about SystemIdle, but it works well. The Dispatcher use is necessary (it can be done with Tasks or Observables or whatever else you want) because the changes are coming from another thread, thus the event is being fired on another thread.

Comment: @Matt West: Another change to the code. If the `e.Action` is `Reset`, `e.NewItems` is null. I am now just checking if `e.NewItems == null`, but you might also want to do different things based off of the e.Action.